# Bottom Navigation hide on scroll Recycler view issue

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

I am using AHBottomNavigation
[This Tutorial](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)

Problem is Bottom Navigation bar hides when i scroll list, how to stop hiding bottom Navigation bar on list view scroll.

Scrolling Behavior is like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/master/demo3.gif) 
But I want to fix(Always visible) Bottom Navigation bar. How to stick this bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AHBottomNavigation` view has a method [setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(boolean behaviorTranslationEnabled)](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/ahbottomnavigation/src/main/java/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/AHBottomNavigation.java#L1017). When disabled, the view won't scroll (according to `AHBottomNavigationBehavior`'s method [`handleDirection(V child, int scrollDirection)`](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/ahbottomnavigation/src/main/java/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/AHBottomNavigationBehavior.java#L127)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(boolean behaviorTranslationEnabled)` and pass `false` inside that. That method is available in you library class.

You might have done this

```
AHBottomNavigation aHBottomNavigation = new AHBottomNavigation();
```

you just need to do this

```
aHBottomNavigation.setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @NaeemIbrahim Glad! it helped you. :)

Comment: @NaeemIbrahim You may accept my answer if it really helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work, I also have the same issue.

```
AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation = new AHBottomNavigation();
bottomNavigation.setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: mention not bro